# Selecting activeworksheet only when it exists in the workbook

Tags: vba, vb.net, excel-2016

I have a VBA module where I want to select a worksheet, but only if it is present in the workbook.

So if I use activeworksheets code this gives an error if the worksheet is not in the workbook.

I have these for 3 worksheets, so I have tried if error but this only works if one of the worksheets is missing, as if error only handles the first case and cannot handle further cases.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please read on how to ask a question on stackoverflow. For people to suggest you answers, put in the sample code snippet or the code that you have already tried and people will be glad to help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this. My suggestion is doing

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(1)
if ws.Name == "Worksheet I want"
    'Do your thing
End if
```

Idk how many sheets you have. Use a for with `Application.Sheets.Count` if you need to.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response it is helpful and I can apply this if the worksheets always remain the same. The only problem I have now is there number of sheets can change, the sheet names are fixed but may not always appear in the workbook. What code would you write for this?

Comment: As I said, count the sheets with `Application.Sheets.Count` and iterate trough them with a for. For each one of them, check the name. If the name is missing, the Worksheet is not on your Workbook.